# NPE when using map {} on ArrayList containing NULLs

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin, nullpointerexception, null

I'm getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'float java.lang.Number.floatValue()' on a null object reference

on following code:

```
val localHistory: ArrayList<Float> = ArrayList<Float>()
...    
val strHistory = localHistory.map { value -> decoration.decoratedValue(ref.format, value) }
```

I've just learned that ArrayList may contain nulls (oookay). That would mean that the *value* in the map transforming closure may be NULL, no?

But this cannot be since the *value* is not an optional type and the compiler says that if (value != null) will be always true.

So the question is how to avoid NPE in this case?

Comment: How are you filling the `ArrayList`? are you doing it in kotlin or java?

Comment: Good question. It's actually deserialized by GSON so it should be Java

Comment: Of course, the list can contain `null`. In that case, auto-unboxing will fail (converting from `Float` to `float`) which obviously is done here. Once this auto-unboxing has succeeded, the variable `value` (which is obviously a primitive `float`) cannot be `null` anymore.

Comment: Can the Json contain any `null` values? If yes, mark the collection you get from java as `ArrayList<Float?>` and then filter the possible `null` values out

Comment: So what are my options to prevent this from failing?

Comment: I am not familiar with Kotlin. In plain Java you could filter out `null` elements: `localHistory.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(...)`. But maybe you should clarify first whether `null` values are allowed or not, or how to deal with them when they occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest marking every parameter in a `Collection` you receive from Java as nullable (unless of course you know it **can never** be `null`:

```
val floats: List<Float?> = someJavaClass.getFloats()
```

Then you can filter out the `null`s and do your map operation:

```
val newFloats: List<Float> = floats
    .filter { it != null }
    .map { it + 1 }
```

Keep in mind that every `filter`, `map` (and so on) operation will iterate the whole collection and create a new on everytime. You're better of using `Sequence`s, which are iterated lazily.

As mentioned in the comments one may use `filterNotNull` to directly filter out all null values:

```
val newFloats: List<Float> = floats
    .filterNotNull()
    .map { it + 1 }
```

And `mapNotNull` to only keep values which map-function doesn't return `null`, this also eliminates the `filterNotNull`:

```
val newFloats: List<Float> = floats
    .mapNotNull { it?.plus(1) }
```

Another construct I can think of which works with your example though it is highly unreadable and just complex. But here it is:

```
val strHistory = localHistory
    .mapNotNull { decoration.decoratedValue(ref.format, it ?: return@mapNotNull null) }
```

Comment: Also note you can use `filterNotNull()` instead of `filter { it != null }`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to exclude the null values in the `ArrayList`, call `mapNotNull` instead of `map`.  See [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html) for details.

You then also need to handle the case where the `value` is null inside your lambda, which you can do with the `?.let` as shown below:

```
localHistory.mapNotNull { value -> value?.let { decoration.decoratedValue(ref.format, it) } }
```

Comment: I get compiler suggestion that it's not necessary when I try to use mapNotNull

Comment: Change the declaration to `ArrayList<Float?>` to tell the compiler that the list might contain null entries.

Answer (score 0):

One more with mapNotNull:

```
val strHistory = localHistory.mapNotNull { it ?: return@mapNotNull null
    decoration.decoratedValue(ref.format, it) }
```